# How can I retrieve all the records which are created on particular date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm confused between timestamp(created_at), and `today`

I want to show the report of last 7 days including today.
The report tells the number of all the comments posted on each day.

How can I fix my code below? What comes to ?????

```
<% user_ids = User.all %>
<% commentable = User.base_class.name.to_s %>

<% check_date = Date.today - 7 %>

<% 7.times do %>

    <% @comments_count = Comment.where(:deleted_at => nil, :created_at => , ??????? :user_id => user_ids, :commentable_type => commentable).count %>    

    <%= @comments_count.to_s %> comments posted! on <%= check_date.to_s %> <br />

    <% check_date = check_date + 1 %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
range = "created_at #{(5.days.ago.utc...Time.now.utc).to_s(:db)}"
Category.where(:conditions => range)
```

A good reference for you: [Rails/SQl query help: Find all by created_at in past 7 days per each day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917822/rails-sql-query-help-find-all-by-created-at-in-past-7-days-per-each-day)

---

For your question:

```
<% user_ids = User.all %>
<% commentable = User.base_class.name.to_s %>

<% 7.times do |i| %>

    <% check_date = Date.today - i %>
    <% date_range = "#{(7.days.ago...check_date).to_s(:db)}" %>

    <% @comments_count =  Comment.where(:deleted_at => nil, :created_at => date_range, :user_id => user_ids, :commentable_type => commentable).count %>

    <%= @comments_count.to_s %> comments posted! on <%= check_date.to_s %> <br />

    <% check_date = check_date + 1 %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you please customize my original code to make me understand deeper? I want to go with my code.

Comment: Thanks, but you should definitely try them both & see which works best. @Amit Thawait's code is programmatically cleaner than mine

Answer (score 4):

You should do something like this

```
<% user_ids = User.all %>
<% commentable = User.base_class.name.to_s %>

<% dates = (Date.today)..(Date.today - 6)  %>

<% dates.each do |date| %>

    <% @comments_count = Comment.where(:deleted_at => nil, :user_id => user_ids, :commentable_type => commentable).select{|comment| comment.created_at.to_date == date}.count %>    

    <%= @comments_count.to_s %> comments posted! on <%= date.to_s %> <br />

<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Can you put `date` directly to inside of `where()`? Because, `date` is datetime, and `created_at` is timestamp

Comment: Also can't you use my `check_date`? instead of using `dates`

Comment: check_date is not required since,we are looping using dates itself and please try my updated answer and let me khow if it doesn't works..

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Don't make queries in your views, use the controllers to get the data and pass them to the views. If you are going to develop with Rails go with conventions and follow the principles (in this case MVC).

You can get all the comments from the last 7 days with:

```
@comments = Comment.group('date(created_at), user_id') :conditions => { :created_at => 7.days.ago.utc...Time.now.utc }
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @comments.each do |date, count| %>

<%= date %>
<%= count %>

<% end %>
```

NOTE: I haven't tested the code